# Одна Cookie на два разных сайта

Tags: java, cookie, tomcat, сессия

Есть проект. У этого проекта есть Админ панель и есть скрипт. Этот скрипт встраивается на другие сайты путем вставки тега `<script />` в `head` сайта.

Есть сайт, на который вставили этот скрипт.

Проект крутится на Tomcat. Соответственно в куки ставиться `id` сессии и пишется он по домену проекта.

Когда загружается скрипт, на том сайте где поставили его, сервер проекта ставит нужные куки для это скрипта и ставит их на домен проекта.

Если смотреть через инспектор в хроме то можно видеть что куки для каждого сайта свои. Если открыть страницу проекта и страницу сайта, на котором стоит скрипт, можно увидеть что `id` этой самой сессии одинаковые. Хотя подождите, разные сайты и разные куки. Как так может быть что кука каким-то образом подтянулась с тех `cookie`?

Comment: Дополни вопрос скринами, т.к. не совсем понятна суть.

Comment: @Темкатоже а что скринить?

Comment: консоль браузера с куками

Comment: Целиком покажите, где какие куки вы видите.